# Loadcontrol event Is working but how?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, loadcontrol

**Page Code :**

```
public partial class Default2 : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Uctest ctrl = (Uctest) this.LoadControl("Uctest.ascx");
        ctrl.ID = "aaa111";
        Page.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
}
```

**Ascx Code :**

```
public partial class Uctest : UserControl
{
    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I have a **page** and **ascx**. the ascx contains **asp:button** and **asp:textbox**

My goal is to reach to the 'btn1_Click' event.

this is working. - when i press the button it goes to the event and its all ok.

but i cant understand why.
because each postback it is RECREATING the CONTROL **AGAIN** , so how does he knows to attch the pressed event to the **upcoming new created ascx** (because of the postback) ??

Comment: mmm... not all the answers ive got - answered my questions...yours does . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post back, you're re-creating the user control.

It is the user control that contains the event method and it is the user control that sets up the event delegation, so it makes sense that each time you create an instance of the user control, it also creates the event method and attaches to it.

Comment: but if each time i would have gave it another Id , it wont be working... so the attachemnt is by the ID ?

Comment: Without seeing how you bind to the event it's hard to say. If you're doing it inline on the control then that has nothing to do with the id

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Uctest.ascx.cs" Inherits="Uctest" %>
<form id="frm" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="press" runat="server" onclick="btn1_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>

Comment: Exactly. You're binding the button the the btn1_Click method inside your user control. So each time you create a new user control, which also creates the event method, you're just attaching to that event. Does this make sense?

Comment: Jamie Dixon  :  i meant that if i press the button in instance #1 of the ascx , so the page reloads - re Generates the ascx ( ver #2). how does the  ascx #2  function is being entered for the event which created by #1  ??